# How do I get moment.tz() to get the timestamp from the internet instead of the user's agent? PC's internal clock off => timestamp is also off

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm running into a bug where if the internal clock of a PC is the wrong time, then moment.tz() returns the wrong timestamp. How can I avoid this in the future? This is for front end based code.

Comment: You can’t. The only timezone it knows about is what’s on the machine the browser is running on.

Comment: There are services which will give you the current time. Some research will bring those to light.